# Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign PDO to property

Tags: php

Hey guys how can i assign PDO to my AbstractRepository class?

I got this error
#Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign PDO to property #

```
class DataBase {
private $conn;
   public static $instance;
    private static $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db';
    private static $username = 'db';
    private static $password = 'db';

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO(self::$dsn, self::$username, self::$password);
        } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            echo 'Problem mit der Datenbankverbindung' . $exception->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        return $this->getInstance()->conn;
    }

}
```

```
abstract class AbstractRepository{
    protected DataBase $connection;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->connection = DataBase::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public function getConnection() { return $this->conn;}` Also `protected DataBase $connection` is a value of type __Database__, and `getConnection` returns a value of type __PDO__.

Comment: i get the same error Fatal error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign PDO to property Shop\Repository\AbstractRepository::$connection of type Shop\Utility\DataBase in /var/www/html/src/Repository/AbstractRepository.php**.

Comment: Once again - `$connection` expects value of type __Database__. `DataBase::getInstance()->getConnection()` returns value of type __PDO__. `PDO` != `Database`

Comment: so how can i just access to the value of type PDO in my AbstractRepository class? and then i want to access  my databank tabel with this code ` class productRepository extends AbstractRepository {  public function getPages() { $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("select * from products"); .... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can return the Value of type PDO

```
class DataBase extends PDO{
   public static $instance;
    private static $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db';
    private static $username = 'db';
    private static $password = 'db';

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            parent::__construct = new PDO(self::$dsn, self::$username, self::$password);
        } catch (\PDOException $exception) {
            echo 'Problem mit der Datenbankverbindung' . $exception->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

}
```

```
abstract class AbstractRepository{
    protected DataBase $connection;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->connection = DataBase::getInstance();
    }
}
```